# How to replace a value in MapSet's Map using a specific key-value pair?

Tags: elixir

I am new to functional programming so I'm struggling with this a little bit.

I am trying to find a Map inside a MapSet through a Key in the Map and then replace a different value. My approach has been, find the Map inside the MapSet and then, remove the Map from the MapSet, replace the value in the Map and add it back in.

```
def replace_in_mapset_by_id(mapset, id, key, value) do
    # Find the Map that matches the ID of the Map we are looking for
    foundMap = (Enum.find(mapset, fn(x) -> Map.get(x, "ID") == id end))

    # Remove the found Map from the MapSet
    remove(mapset, foundMap)

    # Replace the Key Value that we are trying update
    updatedMap = Map.replace(foundMap, key, value)
    add(mapset, updatedMap)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another [I believe more idiomatic] approach would be to use a factory with a transformer [`MapSet.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html#new/2):

```rb
iex|1 ▶ map = MapSet.new([%{id: 1, key: :foo}, %{id: 2, key: :bar}])
#MapSet<[%{id: 1, key: :foo}, %{id: 2, key: :bar}]>

iex|2 ▶ MapSet.new(map, fn                 
...|2 ▶   %{id: 1} = old -> %{old | key: :baz}
...|2 ▶   any -> any
...|2 ▶ end)
#MapSet<[%{id: 1, key: :baz}, %{id: 2, key: :bar}]>
```

Using in your function:

```rb
def replace_in_mapset_by_id(mapset, id, key, value) do
  MapSet.new(mapset, fn                 
    %{id: ^id} = old -> %{old | key => value} # update only
    # %{id: ^id} = old -> Map.put(old, key, value) # update/insert
    any -> any
  end)
end
```